# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector SyntaxError: Unexpected token } using XPath through Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to click the last span element in the following HTML

```html
<div class="rating rating-set js-ratingCalcSet" >
  <div class="rating-stars js-writeReviewStars"> 
    <span class="js-ratingIcon glyphicon glyphicon-star fh"></span>
    <span class="js-ratingIcon glyphicon glyphicon-star lh"></span>
     ...
    <span class="js-ratingIcon glyphicon glyphicon-star fh"></span>
    <span class="js-ratingIcon glyphicon glyphicon-star lh"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

using Selenium in Java, with the following code:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class, 'js-writeReviewStars')]//span)[last()]")).click();
```

This returns an exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//div[contains(@class, 'js-writeReviewStars')]//span)[last()] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
  ...
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=(//div[contains(@class, 'js-writeReviewStars')]//span)[last()]}
```

I have checked the validity of the xpath expression and it seems correct (using https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), as it finds the target element.

I have tried surrounding the whole expression in parentheses, which did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close. To identify the `last()` `<span>` tag within the `<div>` tag you need to remove the extra pair of **`(`** and **`)`** from the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath).

So effectively you need to change:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class, 'js-writeReviewStars')]//span)[last()]")).click();
```

As:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'js-writeReviewStars')]//span[last()]")).click();
```

Comment: I think you have and extra `(` in the starting of xpath